# calculating $ \int_c \frac{\cos(z)}{z^7}$ with $c: \lvert\,z\,\rvert=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate $A=\int_C \frac{\cos(z)}{z^7}dz$ with $C$ the circle $\lvert\,z\,\rvert=2$ in the positive direction.

Clearly, we have  $0 \in C$ and if we let $g(z)=\cos(z)$, it is clearly analytic. Hence, I wrote

$A= \int_c \frac{g(z)}{(z-0)^7}dz =\frac{ g^{(6)}(0) 2 \pi i}{6!}= \frac{- \pi i}{360}$

because $g^{(6)}(z)= - cos(z)$.

But the answer in my book is $\frac{ \pi i}{ 360}$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I got $-\dfrac{i \pi}{360} $, too

Comment: @Raffaele you think there is a mistake in the book?

Comment: I used *Mathematica* to confirm my result which is the same as yours. A little doubt rises...

Comment: @Raffaele  It has been a while since I used mathematica. Can you tell me what  your code was? I will use a similar code to check my answers if I think there are other mistakes in the book.

Comment: 2 Pi I Residue[Cos[z]/z^7, {z, 0}]